# Insert custom annotation in java 'field' using annotate plugin + JAXB (upon xsd -> java)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotate, jaxb2-basics

Use case:

Wanna insert custom annotation to fields in java class generated by JAXB

Problem:

Using Annotate plugin + JAXB [1], am able to successfully insert custom annotations but they are getting inserted at getter method rather than field. Morphia (mongo DB) annotations (that i actually want to insert) however can annotate only java fields [2].

My test xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1"
xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox">

<xsd:element name="hoo" type="External" />
<xsd:complexType name="External">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="bar" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="hoobar" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

My test binding xjb:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
 version="2.1"
 xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

  xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox">
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="external.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

<jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='External']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='bar']">
  <annox:annotate>
    <annox:annotate
      annox:class="java.lang.SuppressWarnings"
      impl="com.acme.foo.MyFieldBridge">
    </annox:annotate>
  </annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

My generated java snippet:

```
 @XmlElement(required = true)
protected String bar;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String hoobar;

/**
 * Gets the value of the bar property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
@SuppressWarnings({

})
public String getBar() {
    return bar;
}
```

As you can see, i want to annotate "bar" field. Please advise. Ask for more if needed.

[1] [Generate @Indexed annotation using Jaxb or HyperJaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343478/generate-indexed-annotation-using-jaxb-or-hyperjaxb)
[2] For sample see @Id annotation of Morphia

Comment: target = "field" 
solves the problem:

  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="external.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='External']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='bar']">
      <annox:annotate target="field">
        <annox:annotate
          annox:class="java.lang.SuppressWarnings"
          impl="com.acme.foo.MyFieldBridge">
        </annox:annotate>
      </annox:annotate>
    </jaxb:bindings>    
    
  </jaxb:bindings>

Let me know if you have any other solution. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: I couldn't post this as answer as i have <100 reputation. Thanks for looking into this anyways.

Comment: How can I insert comments to xsd when generate schema ?

Comment: @wener, its been a long time now and i dont remember. you are better off posting this as new question/comment lexicore (who also gave correct answer) below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, you figured it out yourself. Use `<annox:annotate target="field">` to annotate a field. Other options are:

- setter
- setter-parameter
- getter
- field
- class

See the [documentation](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Annotate+Plugin).

Comment: Thanks much for your reply lexicore.

Answer (score 2):

Just one more thing: you need to put the `field` attribute to the outer `<annox:annotate>` tag:

```
<annox:annotate target="field">
    <annox:annotate annox:class="java.lang.SuppressWarnings"/>
</annox:annotate>
```

Putting it to the same tag as the `annox:class` attribute resides might not work. That happend to me.